# Showing variable labels under the segments of dendrogram with ggdendro

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggdendro

My question is related to Andrie's [answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW0m1.png)  to my earlier question. My question is whether is this possible to display the variable labels and car label under the corresponding segments of the dendrogram?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro)
data(mtcars)
x <- as.matrix(scale(mtcars))
dd.row <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(x))))
ddata_x <- dendro_data(dd.row)
p2 <- ggplot(segment(ddata_x)) +
geom_segment(aes(x=x0, y=y0, xend=x1, yend=y1))
print(p2)
```

[image]

Comment: If you simplify your code to a **minimal** example I shall have a look. For example, if your question is how to add labels at the bottom to a dendrogram, then simplify the code to show a single dendrogram.

Comment: @Andrie : I've updated the question with minimal code. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have version 0.0-7 of `ggdendro` and then use the convenience function `ggdendrogram`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro)
ggdendrogram(dd.row)
```

[image]

If you want full control over how the labels are displayed, you can extract and manipulate these from `ddata_x` using either:

```
ddata_x$labels
label(ddata_x)
```

To add to your plot:

```
p2 + geom_text(data=label(ddata_x), aes(label=text, x=x, y=0))
```

You can find more information in the vignette, `vignette("ggdendro")`