# Labelling ggdendro leaves in multiple colors

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, dendrogram

I have a situation in which i am plotting a dendrogram with data points that come with class labels. 
I wish to see that agglomerative clustering groups those with the same label together. Color coding the labels makes it easy to read such a dendrogram. Is there a way we can achieve this with ggdendro in R ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Stealing most of the setup from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201067/showing-variable-labels-under-the-segments-of-dendrogram-with-ggdendro) ...

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro)
data(mtcars)
x <- as.matrix(scale(mtcars))
dd.row <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(x))))
ddata_x <- dendro_data(dd.row)

p2 <- ggplot(segment(ddata_x)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend))
```

... and adding a grouping factor ...

```
labs <- label(ddata_x)
labs$group <- c(rep("Clust1", 5), rep("Clust2", 2), rep("Clust3", 4))
labs
#     x y text  group
# 1   1 0 carb Clust1
# 2   2 0   wt Clust1
# 3   3 0   hp Clust1
# 4   4 0  cyl Clust1
# 5   5 0 disp Clust1
# 6   6 0 qsec Clust2
# 7   7 0   vs Clust2
# 8   8 0  mpg Clust3
# 9   9 0 drat Clust3
# 10 10 0   am Clust3
# 11 11 0 gear Clust3
```

... you can use the `aes(colour=)` argument to `geom_text()` to color your labels:

```
p2 + geom_text(data=label(ddata_x),
               aes(label=label, x=x, y=0, colour=labs$group))
```

[image]

(If you want to supply your own colors, you can use `scale_colour_manual()`, doing something like this:

```
p2 + geom_text(data=label(ddata_x),
               aes(label=label, x=x, y=0, colour=labs$group)) +
     scale_colour_manual(values=c("blue", "orange", "darkgreen"))
```

Comment: Thank you! I am relatively new to R, this helps me a lot.

Comment: Running your code, I get 2 errors: 
1) in `geom_segment`, it can't find `x0` but this is simply fixed by changing the arguments in `x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend`; 
2) in `geom_text`, it says: `Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous
Error in data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), y = 0, label = function (x,  : arguments imply differing number of rows: 11, 1, 0`. How can I fix it? Because I have a similar case to deal with (i.e. coloring labels) and provides the same error.

Comment: @DavidePassaretti -- With help from Andrie de Vries (**ggdendro**'s author) and Roland (another SO regular), I've edited the code so that it works with the current version of **ggdendro**. Thanks for the heads up that this answer was no longer functional!

Comment: Is there a way to color the leaves instead of coloring the labels? Thanks